# Next.js Link tag rendering on the page [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi I'm trying to make breadcrumbs for a page this is the breadcrumb array what it looks like:

`const breadcrumbs = ['Home', "Men's Top", 'Winter Jacket']`

so in JSX I'm trying to render this array using Next.js

```
import Link from "next/link";

const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {}

    const breadcrumbs = ['Home', "Men's Top", 'Winter Fur']

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ height: "50px", paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
                {
                    `${
                        breadcrumbs.map((crumb, index, array) => {
                            if (crumb !== array[array.length - 1]) {
                                return (
                                        <Link href={index === 0 ? "/" : "/" + crumb}>
                                            {crumb}
                                        </Link> + " > "
                                    )
                            } else {
                                return <Link href={"/" + crumb}>{crumb}</Link>
                            }
                        }).join().replace(/,/g, "")

                    } `
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

So this code renders on the page as `[object Object] > [object Object] > [object Object]`

But without including the Link tag I have `Home > Men's Top > Winter Fur`. Why is Link tag rendering on the page as `[object Object] > [object Object] > [object Object]`? What am I doing wrong as I really need the Link tag to switch between pages?

Comment: Why do you call `.join()` (and `.replace()`) on the result of `.map()`? You want the elements and not their string representations.

Comment: I done .replace() because .map is rendering onto the JSX with commas between the each element so I wanted to remove that @Andreas

Comment: Because of that unnecessary `.join()` call...

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrapped your Link components to the string. Remove `${` from your code

```
        <div style={{ height: "50px", paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
            {
               breadcrumbs.map((crumb) => {
                  return <Link href={"/" + crumb}>{crumb}</Link>
                }).join(' > ')
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: The converstion from object to string happens on the `.join()` call.

Comment: But it's not needed here at all

Comment: Yes, [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942319/next-js-link-tag-rendering-on-the-page-object-object/74942377?noredirect=1#comment132250298_74942319) ;)

Comment: thanks guys I didn't realize I had that ``${`` in the begining lol